# Using taylor series expansion to approximate the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, approximation

[image]

I know that $f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x)$ but I do not know what to do to reach what is shown above, I would appreciate any collaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality  you have  is 
$$\tag1
f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x)+o(h^4).
$$
Also
$$\tag2
f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)-\frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x)+o(h^4),
$$
$$\tag3
f(x+2h)=f(x)+2hf'(x)+2h^2f''(x)+\frac{4h^3}{3}f'''(x)+o(h^4),
$$
$$\tag4
f(x-2h)=f(x)-2hf'(x)+2h^2f''(x)-\frac{4h^3}{3}f'''(x)+o(h^4).
$$
If you use the above, you get 
$$
8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)-f(x+2h)+f(x-2h)=12hf'(x)+o(h^4),
$$
which gives the first formula. The second one is similar.

Comment: Is the idea then to take the limit as $h \to \infty$? Maybe the h's cancel in some cases.

Comment: The idea is to establish the approximations to $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ from the OP. Not sure what you mean by "the $h$'s cancel".

Comment: The approximation of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ depends on some small $h>0$ so I was confirming that you could take the limit as $h \to 0$ since you have expressions in terms of $h$ on the RHS.

Comment: I meant that for $f'(x)$ the $h$ in the numerator may cancel with the $h$ in the denominator hence no need for taking the limit.

Comment: Cancelling in that sense would be extremely unusual, it would happen for just a handful of functions. The $h$ does not have to be positive. And yes, these are approximations, so the smaller the $h$, the better the approximation. As mentioned in the question and in the answer, these are $o(h^4)$, which means that they are much better than the naive approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeatedly use $\sum_i c_i f(x+ih)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\dfrac{h^n\sum_i c_i^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)$, where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative of $f$ (in particular, $f^{(0)}=f$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f(x+ h)= f(x)+ hf'(x)+ \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+ \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(x)$ so $f(x+ 2h)= f(x)+ 2hf'(x)+ \frac{4h^2}{2}f''(x)+ \frac{8h^3}{6}f'''(x)$, $f(x- h)= f(x)- hf'(x)+ \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)- \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(x)$, and $f(x- 2h)= f(x)- 2hf'(x)+ \frac{4h^2}{2}x^2- \frac{8h^3}{6}x^3$.

Add those.